# Replicating Django apps from reusable packages

Tags: python, django

I am trying to leverage off the available Django Package, [`andablog`](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-andablog/). I have installed the necessary packages from PyPI. However, I noted that even after including the following code within `settings.py`, the command `python manage.py migrate` does not create the necessary app folders within the project folder. Am I missing some other steps?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_markdown',
    'service_reviews',
    'andablog',
    'taggit',
    'markitup',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`python manage.py migrate` is not supposed to create any directory, its goal is to generate the database tables required for your installed apps to work properly (read the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/) for more info).

The third party apps that you installed live somewhere in your Python path and Django knows how to access them, you don't need them to be in your project's folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing any steps, but you shouldn't expect `andablog` to be a local Django app -- that's not what adding third-party apps to `INSTALLED_APPS` should do. `INSTALLED_APPS` informs Django of what packages it needs to load upon bootstrapping. Migrating the app will put migrations in a different directory altogether. The exact location of these migration files will vary depending on how you [installed the package](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#how-installation-works).